# Set an element's width to a percentage of its grandparent

Tags: html, css

[image]
**not drawn to scale*

I've been trying to come up with some CSS to achieve what I am depicting in this picture. Where I have a Stage which defines the size of what is visible and a Slider element which contains all of the elements so you can scroll/slide between elements. Any of the overflow from Stage will be hidden, so you will only be able to see the 3 elements.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to define an Element's width as a third of the Stage (x/3 and x in this picture). I can't inherit the Element's parent's width since that will be larger as the amount of containers.

Now, I have two questions regarding this.

1. How I can make Slider adjust it's width automatically without setting it to a value like `500%`? Right now, Slider is `position: absolute` and `width: 500%` with Stage being `position relative`.
2. Can Element be a 3rd, 4th, or some percentage of Stage without the use of Javascript or hardcoded values?

Lack of support for IE is perfectly fine and preferably without the use of JS for resizing/calculating widths.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/karp5786/) of what I have.

Comment: Demo with what you achieved so far please

Comment: @NunoArruda added a demo

Comment: You need to re-assign slider's and element's width `onresize` event.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I'm not using any javascript with this and would like to see if it's possible without using it to calculate widths/resize things.

Comment: are you okay with a less/scss soultion ? In that we can store stage width in a variable and then for element width it would be variable/3.

Comment: @Ajey I'd prefer to stay away from hard coded values so a Stage could be relative to it's parent container without having to change the CSS.

Comment: @allejo But you would hardcode the container width right ?

Comment: @Ajey the way I'm intending on using this would be `.parent > .stage` and `.parent` would be 80% of its container and `.stage` would be 100% of `.parent` or `.stage` itself could be `80%` without a parent; whichever method would work.

Comment: @allejo: Why do really need a slider? Why can't your `.element`s be direct children of `.stage`?

Comment: @Abhitalks I'm using the Slider so I am able to move that element by setting `left` or `right` through Javascript. If there's a better way of achieving this without that container, I'd be fine with that too

Comment: @allejo: See here -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mx33zd82/

Comment: @Abhitalks seems like I was overcomplicating things, that would actually work perfectly! and instead of me using `left`, I'd just use `margin-left` instead. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `display` of slider to `table` and treat each element as `table-cell`.
And provide min and max width of element to one constant value.

[Pen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGJGby)

```
<div class="stage">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.stage {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: table;  
  border-spacing: 20px;
}

.element {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  display:table-cell;
  height: 300px;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:300px;
}
```